# Можно ли получить разницу дат от age на русском?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

```
select age(timestamp '2001-04-10', timestamp '1957-06-13')
```

Возвращает

> 43 years 9 mons 27 days

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону функции to_char. https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/functions-formatting Пример:
SELECT TO_CHAR(age(timestamp '2001-04-10', timestamp '1957-06-13'), 'YY "Года" MM "Месяцев" DD "Дней"') as age